# CloudFront delivery is slow in particular location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, geolocation, monitoring, amazon-cloudfront

In my scenario, I found that our CloudFront delivery in the Japan area is particularly slow for a few days. which lead our site to become slow in the time of loading the media contents .our s3 origin is in the Northern Virginia region.
what might be the possible issues of this? or if something is not configured correctly? How do investigate the issue can anyone suggest me?

Are Cache key and origin requests to Cache policy and origin request policy (recommended)changes will improve the performance?

Screenshots of the CloudFront settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me with this? is there a better way to identify the root cause of this? Is there any scope to find out the actual region behind it, or do we rely on any log data, monitoring system in suggestion ??

Comment: Any chance you can show how you are measuring the speed problems ?

Comment: What parts are loading slowly, are you measuring load time or speed in a specific way and what are the results of that test?  Is your s3 origin also in Japan or is it based in some other region?

Comment: our site to become slow in the time of loading the media contents in japan region .our s3 origin is in the Northern Virginia region, is there any scope to find out the actual region behind it, or do we rely on any log data, monitoring system you suggest ??

Comment: Is Cache key and origin requests to Cache policy and origin request policy (recommended)changes will improve the performance?

Comment: Duplicate: https://serverfault.com/questions/1091355/cloudfront-delivery-is-slow-in-particular-location